# how to properly execute mysqldump through php

Tags: php, mysql, database

After a database is successfully inserted with data, I want now to backup the database. Since this is a script done in codeigniter, I created this function below.

This is bugging me for a while. I want to execute a php script that contains command line.

Here is my code:

```
public function backupDb()
        {
                log_message('debug', 'Preparing to Back-up Database...');

                $dbuser = "root";
                $dbpass = "root@111";
                $dbname   = "listingdb";
                $dumpfile = $dbname . "_" . date("Ymd") . ".sql";

                $command = "mysqldump -u $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > $dumpfile";

                exec($command);
        }
```

I tried manually doing this code;

```
mysqldump -u root -proot@111 listingdb > listingdb_20171013.sql
```

and it Successfully creates a .sql file

But my function seems to not work. How can I do it right?

Comment: Cron seems like a better tool to do this.

Comment: I am not required to do cron in this task.